# Local variable and memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I am reading some things around, and came across this:

> Destructors are called when variable goes out of scope

So my question is what happens with variables that do not have destructors?

As an example:

```
class A {
    public:
        A () { }
};

void foo () {
    A a;
}

int main (void) {
    foo();
}
```

So in this instance is `a()`? Is memory that was allocated for `a` destructed after `foo()` is done or not?

Than I have this example:

```
class A {
        std::vector <int> aa;
    public:
        A () : aa(5) { }
};

void foo () {
    A b;
}

int main (void) {
    foo();
}
```

In this case as well is memory that was allocated for `b` destructed after `foo()` is done or not?

One more clarifications, I know this:

```
class A {
    public:
        A () { }
};
```

is equivalent to

```
class A {
    public:
        A () { }
        inline ~A() = default;
};
```

But my question is, is this inline destruct called when `foo()` is done?

EDIT:
When was `inline` destructor added as default?

Comment: `A a();` -- This does not create an object.  This declares a function called `a()` that takes no parameters and returns an `A` object.

Comment: @Gox The call to _`foo();`_ in `main()` would probably optimized out by any decent c++ compiler, since that function doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Sidenote: The destructor does not free the memory of the object being destroyed. It is most often called as part of the chain leading to the freeing of memory, but can be invoked separately  to destroy an object without releasing the memory. See [Placement new/delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)  for more about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.dtor#4):

> If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted [([dcl.fct.def])](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def). An implicitly-declared destructor is an `inline public` member of its class.

In other words,

```
class A {
    public:
        A () { }
};
```

is equivalent to

```
class A {
    public:
        A () { }
        inline ~A() = default;
};
```

As for your question

> But my question is, is this inline destruct called when `foo()` is done?

The answer is yes. However, that is true even for a user defined destructor.

Comment: @Gox, are you trying to find out when the destructor is called?

Comment: @Gox, who is talking about memory leak for such objects?

Comment: @Gox, I hear your frustration. I hope you stick with language. Like any learned skill, it gets easier with practice. Best of luck.

Comment: *are you trying to find out when the destructor is called?* Yes. *Who is talking about memory leak for such objects?* some old **Learn C++ easily tutorial**. It was somebody's recommendation that I should read this printed version of that tutorial.

Comment: @Gox, inline destructors have been around for a long time. I have been using it since 1995. It certainly has been part of the C++98 standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide a destructor, the compiler will provide one for you. This destructor will call the destructors of any member variables and base classes.

There are a few cases in which you must write a destructor to avoid leaks. One case is if you're holding a bare pointer to something allocated with `new` and your object is the best candidate for 'owning' that pointer. In most cases, when you allocate something with `new` you consider yourself the owner of the pointer.

Another case is when you've acquired some other sort of resource and need to release it. For example, if you open a file, or socket, you probably will need to write a custom destructor to close it.

Though, what I do for all such resources is that I make a class that wraps the resource and has a destructor that closes it. This localizes the issue so I have to remember as little as possible with regards to resource management for most of my code. This is a common idiom in C++ and is referred to as *RAII*, meaning "Resource Acquisition Is Initialization".

This is also why you should prefer `make_unique` and `make_shared` or things like `vector` to allocating memory with `new`. They give you objects that wrap the memory resource who's destructors will automatically release the resource for you.

To answer the question in your comment on my answer more thoroughly...

A local variable's destructor is called as soon as control leaves the block it was declared in. For a concrete example:

```
void foo () {
    A b;
    {
        A c;
    } // Destructor for c is called here
} // Destructor for b is called here.
```

Comment: @Gox - Yes, for a variable on the stack, the destructor is called when the block it was declared in exits.

Comment: @Gox - I added a more complete answer to your question in the comment to my answer. And, you're welcome.